# Where does Telegram save files in Linux?

Tags: browser

Any idea where does [web-based Telegram](https://web.telegram.org/) save files in Linux?

Comment: A crude way is to use `find`. (The first run of `find` takes a little while; subsequent runs are faster.) To use `find` for your purpose, close all non-essential applications that may otherwise contribute to the output. Save a file in your Telegram program, and then immediately run `find -newermt "10 sec ago"`. You'll get a list which you can look over for relevant hits. (Much of the "noise" will come from your browser caching stuff and the browser's other housekeeping activities).

Comment: This might depend upon which browser you are using.